How do Azure Cognitive Service jobs work?
I am doing an import to the languge service using the import rest api. A repsonse header returns an operation-location, which is a URL for checking the status of the import.
It looks like this:

lang001.cognitiveservices.azure.com:443/language/query-knowledgebases/projects/myProject/import/jobs/d9ac9c56-962f-4a4f-8254-f94feed95a55?api-version=2023-04-01

How can I find infomraiton on this job?
Is it possible to see it in the UI, or to see log informaiton on the job?
Is the job running in the language resource, or the coresponding search resource, or somewhere else?

Refer to this link to get the status, such as succeeded etc , using the jobId.

I am doing that now.   I'd like to know where they are running, and see more detialed log information.  I am having trouble with one connecting to a storage account, and it's hard to troubleshoot.  Is it running in the language service, or the associated search service, or comewhere else.

It owkrs, but that is not the answer to my question.  I didn't ask how to get the status.

Good to know it works.What you see in result after running. Is the job running?. Can give more details what all other you dealing with. For know about url tell the infomraiton on this job.

You can get  the status, such as succeeded etc , using the jobId Using this  link
Below code is to get  request to check the deployment status.

const endpoint = "https://<region>.api.cognitiveservices.azure.com"; 
const projectName = "proj1"; //if dont have deployentname keep it as null.
const deploymentName = "Your_deployment_name"; 
const jobId = "your_job_ID"; 
const apiVersion = "2021-10-01";
const subscriptionKey = "your_subscription_key"; 

async function getDeploymentStatus() {
    const url = `${endpoint}/language/query-knowledgebases/projects/${projectName}/deployments/${deploymentName}/jobs/${jobId}?api-version=${apiVersion}`;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Deployment Status:', data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch deployment status:', error);
    }
}


getDeploymentStatus();


Output:


According to this documentation, in the context of using Azure OpenAI with your data, the job ID for an ingestion job is typically generated when you initiate the ingestion process through Azure OpenAI .


For the image above, go to Language >> Features and select Enable custom question answering. Then, choose the Azure Search resource to link to and enable Custom Text Classification / Custom Named Entity Recognition in storage.
